# Windows, Mingw Qt Application Does Not Run On Deployed Computers

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4

I have created a Qt application with Mingw.  The application runs properly on the development computer after copying the required DLL's to the directory.  However, when deploying on external computers, the application does not run at all.

Update:
In addition, the application uses Sqlite3 via QtSql.

Comment: what errors do the user's see?

Comment: No errors.  The windows hour glass shows and then nothing happens.  I'm the user at this point, its not deployed in production yet.

Comment: Have you tried running it under the debugger? GDB is probably your best bet for a MinGW-compiled program, but if the problem is in a system DLL you might need to use something like cdb from the Debugging Tools for Windows package in the Windows SDK. You can get GDB from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/BaseSystem/GDB/GDB-7.2/gdb-7.2-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma/download and it needs libexpat-1.dll from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/expat/expat-2.0.1-1/libexpat-2.0.1-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.gz/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite likely you're still missing some dll.

1. Check the Windows event log for any errors after running the application. (Administrative Tools->Event Viewer).
2. Try launching the application from a command prompt window.
3. Try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Another thought is some missing configuration file or registry settings.

Double check against the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment-windows.html) for deploying Windows Qt applications.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both already.  Event log had nothing in regards to the application and command prompt displayed nothing. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: @Jason If you didn't already do that, for the command prompt part, you have to recompile your application with `CONFIG+=console` in the .pro file, so that it actually uses the console.

Comment: You turned out to be right, sir!  I had the QtSql dll, however I was missing the SQLITE dll. To be more exact, it was not in the right spot.  Apparently it needs to be in a subdirectory called sqldrivers.  See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151279/qsqlite-driver-not-loaded  Thanks!