# Error connecting mysql database with qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I was trying to connect mysql with qt. But got following error.

```
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

I am using Qt 5.2.1. The code is as follows:
widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

bool Widget::conectar()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("charu");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("admin");

    if(!db.open())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0,"Database Error",db.lastError().text());
        return false;
    }

    QMessageBox::warning(this,"Conexion","Conexion Extitosa");
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SHOW DATABASES");
    QString salida;
    while(query.next())
    {
        salida+=query.value(0).toString()+"\n";    
    }
    ui->textEdit->setText(salida);
    return  true;
}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QSQLITE driver not loaded - where to put qt database driver plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151279/qsqlite-driver-not-loaded-where-to-put-qt-database-driver-plugins)

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem by doing what was done in the above link

Comment: What is the output of `qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();`? Also check if MySQL service is running and listening to port 3306.

Comment: qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers() It shows SQLITE PSQL PSQL7. How can I check that mySQL service is running and listening to port 3306?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @Erik Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @charu you can do `ps faux | grep mysqld` and see if that give you a line a la `/usr/sbin/mysqld` or you can do `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status`. If none of these return anything sensible, then you don't have mysql setup or maybe even installed