# How to fix "driver not loaded" using QODBC in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm working on a project where I need to load a database using QT, and I've built the QODBC plugin using the method provided online, but I still get the "Driver not Loaded" error when trying to access the DB.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=C:\\dbs\\project.mdb");
if(db.open())
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "opened","successful");
else
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "opened", (db.lastError().text() + "\n" + db.driverName()));
```

I have a feeling I'm not including the plugin or something, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Please add `if (! db.isValid()) QMessageBox::warning(this, "setup", "plugin error")` right after the first line and retry. So far you don't know if the error is due to the plugin not being available, or due to wrong arguments to the driver.

Comment: You need to add the directory containing `sqldrivers` to the library path, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31694394/492336. So if you have the driver at `/path/to/sqldrivers/qodbcdriver.dll` (or whatever its name is), you need to call `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("/path/to")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [QSQLITE driver not loaded - where to put qt database driver plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151279/qsqlite-driver-not-loaded-where-to-put-qt-database-driver-plugins)